# PHP callback just before script dies

Tags: php, caching, callback

I have a set of custom PHP scripts. They load a main PHP file (to include other files, set settings, etc.) From this script I'd like to insert a callback function that is called by the scripts that included the main file just before ending.

What I intend to do is make a simple custom output cache with `ob_get_contents()`. I want to do `ob_start()` in main.php, then have the callback function store the output.

Comment: Please rephrase this as a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ob_start()`](https://www.php.net/ob_start) can do what you want:

```
ob_start('store_output');

function store_output($output) {
  // do something with $output
  return $output;
}
```

When the output buffer is flushed, the function will be called. Output buffers can be nested.

Comment: What would happen if you called ie. ob_get_clean()?

Comment: It would call the callback. Is that desired behaviour?

Comment: Oops, I should have looked at the PHP documentation first :). That's exactly what I need!

Comment: I don't know, I'm not the OP! I was just curious.

Answer (score 4):

See [`register_shutdown_function`](https://www.php.net/register_shutdown_function):

> Register a function for execution on
> shutdown

Example from the manual:

```
<?php
function shutdown()
{
    // This is our shutdown function, in 
    // here we can do any last operations
    // before the script is complete.

    echo 'Script executed with success', PHP_EOL;
}

register_shutdown_function('shutdown');
?>
```